# Postgres occasionally slow to query

Tags: postgresql, performance, amazon-rds, connectivity, query-performance

I'm running a database with a few tables with large row counts (millions) but which are fairly small in data size. All the tables are append-only, so no deletes or updates ever happening, around 250 rows are added per minute. 99% of the time queries take less than 5ms. However, occasionally queries get terminated by Postgres for taking more than 200ms (my configured statement timeout).

I'm using default settings apart from `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor`=0.05, `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor`=0.1 and `autovacuum_naptime`=30.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on AWS RDS on a t2.medium machine, with multi-az and connecting to it from AWS Lambda (Node.js 6.10) from within the same private VPC.

CPU stays under 7% at all times, disk read latency is less than 2 ms, number of concurrent connections rarely goes above 1. Average queries per second is quite consistent at around 20.

We've also tried turning `synchronous_commit` to `off`, but the same timeouts continued to happen.

Could this be an issue with the auto-vacuum process slowing queries even though I've got no updates or deletes?

Update: Having removed all writes to the database, we still see the same issue. So, no inserts, no updates, no deletes, just ~30 selects per second causes timeouts.

Comment: vacuum shouldn't block reads. check pg_locks and pg_stat_activity next time before you kill the processes.

Comment: To clarify, I've never actually had to kill any process - it's only ever a single query that fails, then it returns to normal within 1 second, so no time to look into other stats while it's failing.

Comment: @danielrbradley, does your table happen to have a `GIN` index? I'm struggling with an intermittent-slow-queries issue, and [I think](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202583/occasional-intermittent-slow-10-second-update-queries-on-postgresql-table-wi/202584) it's related to Postgres's `FASTUPDATE` mechanism on a `GIN` index.

Comment: @ChrisW. nope fraid not - only simple indexes on the bigserial type

Comment: did you find the reason of problem?  we have same issue

Comment: Nope, never resolved it. Decommissioned that project ... going with MySQL next time ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately don't know much about postgres on AWS, my company is just starting to move that way, but when a vacuum runs here it does create disk io that could potentially slow down a query.  It could be that the locks are on resource contention more as opposed to Postgres Locks.